# Monitor errors of the Optimistic Response

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo

Is there any way to monitor failure of the optimistic response mechanism?

Let's say I have a `mutation` with `optimisticResponse` option, but the body of the `optimisticResponse` is missing an essential field of the returned object. In that case Apollo Client will fail trying to update the relevant cached item, with the following error message `Invariant Violation: Missing field...`

I tried using `onError` and pass it to the `link` field of the `ApolloClient` instance but it reflecting only network or GraphQL policy errors, not the optimistic response error I'm looking for.